DKIM for MacOS - OpenDKIM or something else?
As a kind of hobby project I've installed dovecot and postfix on an old home server running MacOS 12.7.6. After a lot of faffing around, it's working and i can send and receive public emails ok.
Now I want to add some DKIM authentication and the community says "use OpenDKIM". At least it used to. It seems that OpenDKIM isn't really being maintained and I can't find any prebuilt binaries for MacOS and when I try and build it from source, the package seems to require an ancient version of automake that I can't find on homebrew and I've run into the sand.
Two questions then, really.

Has anyone had recent (i.e. 2023 or newer) experience of building
opendkim on MacOS. And,
given the more-or-less fossilised state of OpenDKIM is there a better/newer DKIM solution for dovecot/postfix that I should be investigating?

steps taken so far...

Looked for opendkim on homebrew - no luck

Looked for opendkim binaries on sourceforge and github. Didn't find
any MacOS binaries, but did find some old tarballs on sourceforge.

Couldn't see how to build from source from the GitHub repo, so...

Downloaded the latest source tarball (2.10.3) from sourceforge and
tried to build it.

The following seemed to complete ok
./configure --with-milter --with-unbound

but then when I did the make step I got
"automake-1.13" is missing on your system


Checking "brew info automake", I have automake 1.17. I tried to install the specific 1.13 version from homebrew but it's too old. There was an option to download the whole homebrew repo locally and try build automake 1.13 from that, but I chickened out.

and here we are...



Search for the source with opensuse, there are number of patches within the srpm. I cannot guarantee that they will work.
